# 3 pin Gas Discharge Tube (GDT) - pinout order

Tags: protection, gas, gdt, ionization

I would like to know the reason behind the pinout order of a 3 pin GDT.

> GDTs are designed to prevent damage from transient disturbances by acting as a “crowbar” in creating a short-to-ground circuit during conduction - Bourns Inc.

A 3 pin GDT has the ability to protect two signals, with the other pin being the one connected to ground. From what I've seen (not much, really), the middle pin is the one being connected to ground (according to the manufacturer). Is there a reason behind this? I would think that this is mainly because of the design convenience or because of industry standards, but I'd like to know if there is also a "chemical" reason behind this (maybe the way gasses behave internally).

[image: 3 pin GDT]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two independent gas-filled cavities with contacts at either end. The center contacts are two sides of the same disk, so the centre disk should be grounded.